# How to count multiple ranges that have a status next to them?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to count multiple matching ranges that also contain "Done" next to them.

Currently, I am able to use this query to count the Totals, but can't figure out how to make sure it only counts the ones that are "Done"

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF('Subject'!A:A,'Jobs'!A:A))
```

This is the desired result:

Results Sheet [image: result sheet screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `VLOOKUP` with `ARRAYFORMULA` to fetch the statuses of the column and `COUNTIF` to match only the "Done" status.

For First:

`=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Subject!A:A, Jobs!A:B, 2, FALSE)), "Done")`

For Second:

`=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Subject!B:B, Jobs!A:B, 2, FALSE)), "Done")`

[image: output]

Comment: This did not work, although it seems the tables I posted didn't show properly which is why there may be a misunderstanding of the requirements.  I took a screenshot of the example that will hopefully clarify.  Thank you for taking the time to reply!!

Comment: Will modify the answer based on the expected output.. Thanks for clearing it up

Comment: Hi @Scott , I have updated my answer and it worked on your test case, kindly check. If it worked on your side as well, feel free to upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Scott, sorry if this is redundant, but if your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer